# Using Timeshift gives - rsync error: some files/attrs

Tags: rsync

Ubuntu 16.04

Started using Timeshift - seems like a nice program but every attempt to restore gives the above error.  Restore log is copied below

```
2017/03/29 11:22:31 [2807] building file list
2017/03/29 11:22:32 [2807] done
2017/03/29 11:22:33 [2807] >f..t...... home/kerry/.local/share/zeitgeist/activity.sqlite-shm
2017/03/29 11:22:33 [2807] >f..t...... home/kerry/.local/share/zeitgeist/activity.sqlite-wal
2017/03/29 11:22:33 [2807] .d..t...... timeshift/
2017/03/29 11:22:33 [2807] .d..t...... tmp/
2017/03/29 11:22:38 [2807] rsync: readdir("/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic/include/config/snd/cs46xx/new"): Input/output error (5)
2017/03/29 11:22:38 [2807] IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion
2017/03/29 11:22:39 [2807] sent 12,060,739 bytes  received 69 bytes  4,824,323.20 bytes/sec
2017/03/29 11:22:39 [2807] total size is 6,931,567,933  speedup is 574.72
2017/03/29 11:22:39 [2807] rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.1]
```

Thanks in advance